# what is the diffrence between lowercasr and UPPERCASE class name in css?

Tags: css

its define different class names or same class name
for example:
If i assign the class name as test for p tag an write the style by this class name and also write some style for Test class name so what will the result of p tag.
it takes styles from two class name or lower case style

Comment: why don't u test it first.

Comment: actually its working  different class names in my project after some changes like xml includes  then it take it as same class names.  for example i have created two error message in the class name of error and Error: one for session error and another for validation error.....

Answer (score 0):

The client will just take the style from the lowercase `test` class. CSS is case sensitive and thus the class `.test` is different to the class `.Test` or `.TEST`.

Comment: thanks for your response... but both styles are working for single class name like test, any issue if i using xml in my page